# How to assign custom hotkey in Enterprise Architect to an extension sub-menus?

Tags: enterprise-architect

In EA there is possibility to create custom add-ins. For these extensions hotkeys could be assigned to execute specific commands. The link below describes a method based on windows API to define such hotkeys.

http://community.sparxsystems.com/community-resources/805-triggering-add-in-functionality-with-custom-hotkeys-in-enterprise-architect

But isn't there any other more straight forward method to introduce hotkeys to EA?

Comment: AFAIK not from API, you can create an MDG to perform it.

Comment: Do you mean that it's possible to define hotkeys in MDG? If yes, could please provide a link or reference that I can go on with custom hotkeys? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did not have an example since I've never developed an MDG, but see this [link](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1395741975/0#0) and [this](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1389512576/0#0)

Comment: It is not possible to define hotkeys in MDG Technologies, which are *completely different* to Add-Ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the present time, EA does not support AddIn-specific hotkey configuration, nor can it pass raw keyboard/mouse events to Add-Ins. The only workable way is the one described in the article you've referenced.